# Pass exact arguments to function

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command that I constantly use:

`awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n                     ", ""); print $0}'`

to parse data the way I want. Instead of writing this out, I have it saved and I just copy/paste it anytime I want to use it. I would like to turn this into a simple function `fixline.sh` so that instead of doing:

`my_command | awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n                     ", ""); print $0}'`

every time, I could just do:

`my_command | fixline.sh`

but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with `bash`. I tried

`echo "$@" | awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n                     ", ""); print $0}'`

but this does not do what I want. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function

```
fixline() {
    awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n                     ", ""); print $0}'
}
```

then just use as awk will read from standard input just fine (as you already know)

```
my_command | fixline
```

For completeness, though the above is superior in every possible way, it is also possible to use an alias for this specific case

```
alias fixline='awk '\''BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n                     ", ""); print $0}'\'
```

the alias will not work if you ever want `fixline` to take optional arguments though.

Comment: Brilliant. I never thought to just put this as a function in my `.bashrc`, but this does exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother showing the alias. It's harder to read and provides no value over the function.